# Request debugging with Charles - Filtering

Tags: ios, charles-proxy

I am developing iOS app  for request debugging.So that I am using [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) which is kind of great tool! 
I can´t figure out how to hide all the Desktop network-processes which are all shown up in the Charles-console too. The iOS device is connected over an proxy with Charles and work like charm.

How can I filter the the shown requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get the below page when you start **Charles**. In that select **Sequence** tab in the request list.

[image]

You will get next screen with filter option in there. Write your filter word to filter request.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can also mark the hosts you want to see requests from by marking them as focused and then tap the focused tick box and see only the one you marked. See more info here:https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/focus/